# Why does maven 3 report that it's mirroring apache snapshots?

Tags: maven, repository

I've set up a mirror of * in my settings.xml.  When I look at the debug level output of my builds, I see some lines about the mirror.  I would expect "*" wildcard to match everything, which amounts in my case, as I understand it, to the only default remote repository in maven, maven central.

However, it appears that several other repositories are being mirrored.  For instance, this line suggests that my build knows about apache snapshots and its using my mirror to mirror it too.

[DEBUG] Using mirror dev-nexus-as-mirror (http://lava4186:8081/nexus/content/repositories/gold-n-central) for apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots).

Doesn't this line mean that apache.snapshots must be decalred somewhere in my build?  Is it in the super pom for maven 3?  Am I reading this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

That repository could be declared in any pom file for any transitive dependency anywhere in the dependency tree. The mirror configuration you have tells Maven to mirror every download request for any repo through your proxy, regardless of which artifact declared it.

Comment: R U saying it's NOT built in to maven 3 then?